# What would make the soldiers suspicious enough of the messenger to kill him?

Tags: warfare

So, the New United States, located in the DC ruins, has had increasingly strong tensions with the other superpower in the region, the city state of Fredericksburg. They have sent a group of 300 soldiers to Prince William Forest Park, and from what reconnoissance soldiers are saying, they are bringing in cannons, guns, and horses to possible try invading DC. So, they President sends a messenger, called Kody, to try and get the prince of Fredericksburg to come and strike up peace talks. He sails down the Potomac and reaches the forest. He has no visible weapons, and is visibly cheery and happy about the possibility of peace, also, he’s singing songs and skipping about, playing with forest creatures. But, the soldiers are suspicious and he is shot on site. I have a question. What would make the group of soldiers, and the prince, suspicious enough of the messenger to kill him?

Comment: Shot on the site (presumably after interrogation) or shot on sight?

Comment: Why are people voting me down

Comment: @Alexander: It’s a real short interrogation however. He is asked one question, and shot

Comment: Traditionally just telling people something they don't want to hear is good enough reason to get a messenger killed.  The uniform is often irrelevant.

Comment: He says nothing they don’t want to hear. He just starts talking about peace and presidential decrees, until he is shot in the middle of his sentence

Comment: This doesn't seem like a worldbuilding question. Deciphering the motivations of one soldier in your universe seems like an author task. There are an infinite number of motivations: Maybe he/she was simply having a really bad day. Maybe the messenger had a really annoying voice. Maybe drugs. Maybe the messenger had a bounty that they didn't know about. Maybe the messenger's hat had something really offensive written on it. Maybe the soldier had psychiatric problems. Maybe God (or the Devil) made the soldier do it.  Maybe the soldier's buddy made him a stupid bet.

Comment: @user534733: It is not the action of one soldier, but the action of the entire group of military personnel stationed in the Forest. My question is asking what would make the group of soldiers suspicious enough to shot down Kody, remove your vote it close to his question

Comment: Assuming the shooting isn't accidental... Either Fredericksburg just hates the NUS that much... Or they have bad intel of some kind. Maybe somebody told them that the messenger the NUS is sending their way is actually an assassin, or something?

Comment: This leans a little too far into story territory - what your characters will do is, well, a matter for the story

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than it being an accidental weapon discharge or one soldier who, psychologically speaking, should never have been given a gun, the easiest way for dear Kody to be shot would be making him look more like a threat.

For example, Kody was unaware he walked through the territory of leper/smallpox colony that Fredericksburg was keeping in quarantine. The guards that saw Kody had orders to shoot any person coming from that direction regardless of excuses, and one greenhorn solider took that order too seriously.

Or, maybe before Kody left DC, Fredricksburg got bombarded with rumors of suicide bombers from the N.U.S. And really, what kind of person really acts that cheerfully when crossing a de-militarized border. Might suspicious if you ask me, my esteemed prince.

Maybe Kody arrived in civilian clothing as a way of leveling the playing field, but put his shiny cigarette case in his vest pocket. He feels like a smoke, moves his hand too fast, a Fredricksburg solider sees a flash of metal, and Kody gets some new holes in'um.

Or maybe the folks in DC underestimated how intolerant soldiers of Fredricksburg could be when they sent Kody, part of a visible minority group, on this assignment. This one is the weakest, as it makes Fredricksburg look cartoonishly evil, but I thought it might be worth including.

Comment: Well, Kody is generally just a cheerful and kind guy, but I guess the soldiers wouldn’t know. He loves telling jokes and bad puns, and prancing around the N.U.S with a flute singing songs. Kody is a cool guy, just generally misunderstood. I actually based him on the Shakespearean archetype of the fool

Comment: Hey, that flute might be it. A metal rod, 6-12 inches long looks like a handgun barrel  if you gesture with it the wrong way. If his devil-may-care attitude and love of this instrument is already foreshadowed, this could make a very satisfying narrative conclusion.

Comment: Oh yeah, you’re right. Pulling a shiny metal flute out of your pocket does look like a gun

Answer (score 3):

There really isn't enough of a reason to ever shoot a messenger unless your military is ready to take force and is highly aggressive. The nature of a messenger is to deliver news, peace/surrender conditions, diplomacy. In that sense, killing a messenger sends a clear message depending on the case.

If its news, it means your ruler/leader has a bad temper. This leads to messengers with bad news of news that they know your ruler will dislike, not stepping forward and being messengers or failing to deliver the messenger. There are a couple examples on the wikipedia page for "Shooting the messenger", but only receiving good news is a sure fire way to overlook enemy activities.

If its related to peace/surrender or diplomacy, then you are essentially telling the enemy or opponent to screw off and that your ready to fight or ignore them and keep doing what you've already been doing.

Onto the actual question part

The most likely way to kill the messenger is that **they weren't following the instructions of the soldiers**. Likely when the messenger approached the soldiers would ask him to stop and surrender. Disobeying this would lead them to shoot him because he could be a threat and isn't complying.

Next would be if the messenger **makes a sudden move or action which could be mistaken for an attack or an attempt to reach for a weapon**. Your soldiers and people will put their own safety above that of a messenger, especially an edgy one and hence they kill him to ensure they live another day.

With the way your messenger is acting, **they could also think he was diseased, sick or mentally incapable**. Basically **not a actual diplomat or messenger** and hence kill him. Messengers often make it very clear they are a messenger so that they won't get shot, because information can be very important and surrendering early can save a lot of lives or provide more favorable conditions that out right losing and having no choice.

**They could also think he is spying on them**. Although there would be better ways to restrain or restrict him from being able to spy on them, they could just dispose on him. This ties in with the above, because if a messenger was spying, you could just blindfold them and disorient them before moving them to a secure location.

The final reason would be because you have a goal you are going to achieve, like war, hence you don't need a messenger from the enemy because you are going to fight them.

As an extra note, if it was accidental, you would likely send your own messenger with the original messengers personal equipment as well as some form of compensation and a well thought out apology and explanation of why they were killed. Followed by some form of diplomatic conversation about what you were doing.

Comment: The people of N.U.S don’t really like Kody. He is merely tolerated. He is optimistic and kind, but is often seen as a fool. He tells bad jokes and puns, prances around DV with a flute, and is generally a kind of annoyance. He is the presidents nephew, though, so people accept him. But, the only reason he is sent of is because he isn’t seen as, valuable to the new US.

Comment: It feels like your implying that the NUS wasn't really taking the threat seriously or wanted to get rid of him. It doesn't matter the reason though, if a messenger was killed, that shows the enemy is being aggressive, or you sent a bad messenger on purpose to have him killed and give you a reason to attack first. In terms of diplomatic leverage, the presidents nephew is still a valuable piece even if everyone hates him.

Comment: Yeah, they were underestimating the enemy. They thought they had a reasonable army and could win in a war, so they just sent Kody to see if they could save some labor

Comment: But, he is hated, so he’d never be elected as president, except in the unlikely situation that he puts away his foolishness, which, obviously, won’t happen with Kody